# How can I force a Scoped service to be disposed immediately after the Controller action returns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

My ASP.NET Core 2.1 web-application uses Entity Framework 6 by adding my `DbContext` as a scoped service:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    String connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db");

    services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext,MyDbContext>( _ => new MyDbContext( connectionString ) );

    // ...
}
```

My Controllers can then use it directly and ASP.NET Core ensures that the `IMyDbContext` (which implements `IDisposable`) will be disposed after the Controller Action completes... *eventually*.

However I noticed that my `MyDbContext` is not disposed immediately after the action returns (or the action's `Task` completes for async actions) because I was hit by a few bugs where I was inadvertently returning `IQueryable` objects directly to the output formatter (which was a JSON formatter which queried all the navigation properties on my still-connected Entity objects causing a very expensive lazy-load to happen) but I didn't notice this until I had moved on to another task. Whereas if the `MyDbContext` was disposed right after the action returned then the navigation properties would have thrown an `ObjectDisposedException` (i.e. a fast-fail) and I would have fixed it sooner.

Is there a way to get ASP.NET Core to dispose of scoped services immediately after the controller action returns instead of when the request completes?

Comment: Not a general solution, but you could call Dispose on the DbContext yourself through an action filter ;) After all, it shouldn't be a problem that it gets called twice.

Comment: What is the code for return `IQueryable` objects? I think you need to return the objects without query navigation properties instead of disposing the object. If you dispose before the `IQueryable` to `IList` objects, it will throw `ObjectDisposedException`.